# How can I save an HttpRequestMessage to file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am using [OWIN](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) to self host an API within a WPF application.  This is for a tool for a tester who doesn't want to have to enable IIS7.

Inside my Post action I want to be able to save the HTTP Request (`ApiController.Request`) to a file like I can with 
`System.Web.HttpRequest` using `SaveAs`.

However OWIN doesn't provide `HttpContext.Current`(nor `HttpContext.Current.Request`), it's `null`, and I can't find any other way to get at a `System.Web.HttpRequest`.

Is there a way I can save a `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` to a file, or just read it as text from a `Stream`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply serialize any `HttpRequestMessage` and then store it wherever you want, e.g. in a text file. Later, you can read the file and deserialize its contents back into an `HttpRequestMessage` instance.

Comment: How do I serialize the message? It doesn't implement `ISerializable` or have the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: Marius, that really didn't answer the question.  Could you please provide a few details?